# Using a Full Spool of Filament, Read as "Empty"

Tags: filament, xyz-da-vinci-mini-w

I have a cheaper consumer-grade printer that I've owned for a couple of years now. It is an XYZ da Vinci Mini W and it seems to recuperate its incurred losses from selling a cheaper printer by jacking up the prices on their filaments. I don't have much of a problem with this (and I'm not asking to "hack" the chips to let me use cheaper filaments), but I went to switch out my filament with a full one I had laying around and I noticed the chip case it contained was a chip (probably removed by somebody for some odd reason). I used a chip that I had laying around, but the printer read the full spool of filament as "empty" because of the old chip. Because of this, I was wondering if there was a way to force the printer to keep printing when the spool is "empty" or if I can somehow reset the chip.

Answer (score 2):

From what is read online, it depends on the firmware version your printer has. It seems that later versions keep track of tag serials and reports tampered tags as non-genuine tags. The best and [most recent reference found](http://www.soliforum.com/topic/17124/android-app-for-resettingwriting-blank-ntags/) is from 2018 which describes you should be creating new tags instead of resetting existing tags. This involves installing an Android App from unverified source and new "paper" NFC213 tags.